# Наложение результатов совпадений регулярных выражений. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

C#. Имеется регулярное выражение, которое ищет вещественные числа в текстовом файле.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\s]+[+|-]?[\d]+[.]?[\d]?[\s]+");
```

Проверяется, есть ли знаки +/-, обязательная целая часть и необязательная дробная. Также проверяется отделено ли число пробелами. Вот здесь и получается ошибка. Если числа идут одно за другим через пробел, то первое совпадение "отбирает" пробел у второго, и второе число уже не попадает в результат. Как выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: Последний `[\s]+` замените на `(?=[\s]+)`, например. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [\s]+[+|-]?[\d]+[.]?[\d]?[\s]+
> ```

- `[\s]+` => `\s+`
- `[+|-]?` => `[+-]?` - это ошибка, позволяющая вводить `|`
- `[\d]?` => `\d*` - если нет ограничения на один знак после точки
- `[\s]+` => `(?=\s|$)` - проверять, что дальше есть пробел или конец строки, но не брать его в текущее совпадение; `+` становится бесполезен.

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот такое регулярное выражение:

```
[+-]?\b\d+[.]?\d?\b
```

Я не изменил то, что Вы считаете вещественным числом — это на Вашей совести.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Можно еще вас спросить. Почему шаблон `\b` используется после `[+-]?`, ведь он указывает на границу слова.

Comment: @raskopin, потому что в противном случае знак потеряется: `[+-]` не являются частью слова.

Comment: Под такое регулярное выражение, которое вы указали подпадают такие части строки как **9.5** в подстроке  **9.5text** или **5** в  **5text**. Как избежать таких совпадений?

Comment: @raskopin, 5 в 5text эта регулярка проигнорирует. А вот с 9.5text, Вы, в общем случае ничего не можете сделать. К примеру, такое предложение: «Мы работаем лет 5.7 если считать ...». Очевидно, что тут 2 числа: 5 и 7, а любая регулярка поймает тут 5.7